# C++ socket client can't connect to server

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, client, server

The connection works if I do it only on my computer, but I am unable to make a connection from my laptop to my server on my computer.

The code is mostly from the Internet:

Client: http://codebase.eu/tutorial/linux-socket-programming-c/code/tcpclient.cpp

Server: http://codebase.eu/tutorial/linux-socket-programming-c/code/tcpserver.cpp

Can there be a problem because the laptop and the computer are both connected to the same router?

Comment: It's probably your firewall

Comment: On server computer just disable the firewall or do a firewall entry for server port

Comment: Do you mean the OS's firewall? I am on Linux

Comment: Is the client and the server in the same subnet ? If the server is behind a NATPAT  enabled router, it won't receive anything.

Comment: @frostblooded yes, the OS's firewall

Comment: I disabled the iptables on the Linux server, but it still doesn't work. Also, I am not sure if I have a NATPAT enables router. What would that mean and what should I do. The computer and the laptop are both connected to the same router, if that helps.